# Ubuntu 17.10 Keys

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have a problem with my keyboard keys.
If i press a key it will say something else

I am using English(UK) layout

I tried to change the keyboard layout but no luck.

Any help?

**Edit**

Results for:`xmodmap -pke | grep slash`

```
`keycode  20 = minus underscore minus underscore backslash questiondown 
backslash
keycode  28 = t T t T tslash Tslash tslash
keycode  32 = o O o O oslash Oslash oslash
keycode  61 = slash question slash question dead_belowdot 
dead_abovedot dead_belowdot
keycode  94 = backslash bar backslash bar bar brokenbar bar`
```

Comment: i do  not know how to find out what which layout im using

Comment: i am using English(UK) layout

Comment: From a terminal, check the result of `$ xmodmap -pke | grep slash`

Comment: You need to use a keyboard layout which matches your physical keyboard. So in order to help you, we need to know both for which language your physical keyboard is designed and which keyboard layout (a setting) you have applied. A pic of your physical keyboard would help.

Comment: Go to the top right corner set of icons and select the screwdriver-wrench icon to open settings. Then on the left panel select "Region and Language" You will see input sources, and below it the layouts installed. By default it should say "English (UK)" only.

Comment: yes it does, so what know

Comment: it wont say what i want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the settings and in the language section, add English(Australian) as that will correct your keyboard layout.